# Generate labels for radio buttons backed by an enum in a Vaadin 14 web app

Tags: enums, vaadin, renderer, vaadin-flow

In a [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) 14.1 web app, using Java 13, I have defined an enum (see [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)) to back my radio buttons ([`RadioButtonGroup`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/radiobutton/RadioButtonGroup.html)).

```
private enum FilterOrNot
{
    SHOW_ALL( "Show all" ), FILTER( "Filter" );  // Elements defining our enum. Passing our desired display name string to the constructor.
    private String displayName;

    // Constructor
    FilterOrNot ( String displayName ) { this.displayName = displayName; }

    String getDisplayName ( ) { return this.displayName; }
}
```

Notice the `getDisplayName` method to supply the text to be used as labels for my radio buttons.

I have defined successfully my radio buttons backed by this enum.

```
private RadioButtonGroup < FilterOrNot > showAllOrFilter ;
…
showAllOrFilter = new RadioButtonGroup <>() ;
showAllOrFilter.setItems( FilterOrNot.SHOW_ALL , FilterOrNot.FILTER ) ;
```

These radio button appear successfully on screen. But their default titles are the all-caps names of the enum objects: “SHOW_ALL” and “FILTER”. I want the labeling to appear as the mixed-case text “Show all” and “Filter”.

➥ How do I get my radio buttons widget to call the `getDisplayName` of the backing enum and use the returned text as their labeling?

I have seen the [`ComponentRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/ComponentRenderer.html) class that can be assigned via [`RadioButtonGroup::setRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/radiobutton/RadioButtonGroup.html#setRenderer-com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer-). I am guessing that is solution. But I cannot get the syntax right. I suspect have the wrong generics types in the angle brackets, but I am not really sure at all. The manual has only a couple of brief mentions of `ComponentRenderer`, so I am not sure how to utilize this class.

```
showAllOrFilter.setRenderer(
        new ComponentRenderer < RadioButtonGroup, FilterOrNot >( ( FilterOrNot filterOrNot ) -> {
           return filterOrNot.getDisplayName() ;
        })
);
```

Comment: `setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>(FilterOrNot::getDisplayName))` should do it?

Comment: You can put a thumbs up on this issue for adding the standard `setItemLabelGenerator(...)` to the `RadioButtonGroup`
https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-radio-button-flow/issues/107

Comment: @ErikLumme Thanks, I just up-voted that issue: [*Add setItemLabelGenerator shorthand to RadioButtonGroup #107*](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-radio-button-flow/issues/107)

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in the Comments on the Question…

## `RadioButtonGroup` lacks `setItemLabelGenerator`

The `RadioButtonGroup` widget lacks the convenient `setItemLabelGenerator` method seen on similar widgets in Vaadin 14.1. For example, [`Select:setItemLabelGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/com/vaadin/flow/component/select/Select.html#setItemLabelGenerator-com.vaadin.flow.component.ItemLabelGenerator-).

See (and vote for!) the feature-request on this ticket asking for such a method to be added: [*Add setItemLabelGenerator shorthand to RadioButtonGroup #107*](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-radio-button-flow/issues/107)

## Workaround: Call `setRenderer`, passing a `TextRenderer`

Until that feature arrives some day, I suggest you use a [`TextRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/TextRenderer.html) object.

On your `RadioButtonGroup` widget named `showAllOrFilter`, call [`setRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/radiobutton/RadioButtonGroup.html#setRenderer-com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer-), and pass a [`TextRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/TextRenderer.html) made from a method reference for your enum’s `getDisplayName` method.

```
showAllOrFilter                         // Your `RadioButtonGroup` widget.
.setRenderer( 
    new TextRenderer <>( 
        FilterOrNot :: getDisplayName   // Method reference.
    ) 
);
```

So all together, your code would look like this.

```
showAllOrFilter = new RadioButtonGroup <>();
showAllOrFilter.setItems( FilterOrNot.SHOW_ALL , FilterOrNot.FILTER );
showAllOrFilter.setValue( FilterOrNot.SHOW_ALL );
showAllOrFilter.setRenderer( new TextRenderer <>( FilterOrNot :: getDisplayName ) );
```